# Special character "à" not recognized in a path in Windows

Tags: windows, command-prompt

**EDIT** : my original post was about PostgreSQL since I thought there lied the problem. But after the investigation allowed by the comments, it is not a PostgreSQL case, but a more general one related to the Windows' command prompt.

I am trying to use the COPY command to copy a selection in a CSV file in PostgreSQL. For some reason, it is not working. At first I thought it was because of the blank spaces in the names of the folders, but it worked fine when I tested it in another case. Then I thought about the length of the path, but it seems I am far from the size limit.

After further testings, it seems the problem is more related to the fact that my path contains a french special character "à", which is not recognized in the command prompt.

Here is the path :

```
'\\10.000.000.00\data\SIEA\_0 Mise à niveau des boites\Zone NRA de Ferney\Ornex 04-05\APD_e\06_Fichier Adresse - IPE\ZAPM_01281_00004_ADDR_ETR.csv'
```

I tried to replace the character by some others, according to what I found online, but without success, possibly because I didn't find the proper character.

Does anyone have a clue on how to solve this ?

Thanks

Comment: please quote the exact command and exact exception

Comment: @VaoTsun I wrote down the full command, which works fine when the path is smaller, and there are less blank spaces.

Comment: is it command prompt? does dir work?.. `dir "\\10.000.000.00\data\SIEA\_0 Mise à niveau des boites\Zone NRA de Ferney\Ornex 04-05\APD_e\06_Fichier Adresse - IPE\ZAPM_01281_00004_ADDR_ETR.csv"`

Comment: also `à` could potentially be not ANSI

Comment: @VaoTsun the dir does not work, saying the path is not being found. And if the "à" is not ANSI, how can I solve that ?

Comment: well, I would change tags from postgres to windows and command-prompt and ask those guys - you use samba share with not ANSI in windows terminal - my experience here is tiny, once `chcp 65001` and Lucida font helped me

Comment: @VaoTsun Ok, I did that. Thank you for your time :)

Comment: sure. good luck!

Comment: Maybe add an e to the string literal : `TO e'\\10.000....` (or a drive letter:) and: what is `'\Z'` ? Is not a valid backslash escape, IMO.

Comment: @joop the e create an error saying "Invalid argument", and on my computer the folder is referenced as f, but in that case it raise an error saying it doesn't understand the command. I don't understand the second part of your comment, the only '\Z' I see is the beginning of the name of the file I want to append.

Comment: If your filesystem understands forward slaches, I'd swith to forward slashses. And you could test by bilding the path directory at a time, starting with '\\10.000.000.00\` (BTW: looks like a bad directory name; does the FS allow multiple dots in a name?)

Comment: @joop After running some more tests, it really seems that the problem is with the "à" in the path. So I am wondering if it could be possible to write another character that could be understood. What do you think ?

Comment: @CodyGray Indeed, my bad, I am correcting that right away. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @CodeCaster Corrected, I am really sorry.

Comment: @GuiOmClair : this is a windows-thing. You need to find out how the `à` is encoded **on the filesystem**. if it is utf8, then you could use `\xc3\xa1` inside the string (and prefix the string with `e` ) if it is cp1252 you could try `\xe1` inside the path string (and prefix the string with `e` )

Comment: Correction: that should have been `\xc3\xa0` and `\xe0`, respectively.